# What is the maximum number of the difference ‘4’ can occur in any such arrangement.

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is: The twelve integers 1, 2, 3, …, 12 are arranged in a circle such that the difference of any two adjacent numbers is either 2, 3 or 4. What is the maximum number of the difference ‘4’ can occur in any such arrangement.
pls help me, I have no idea about this problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's at most eight, because that's the number of pairs of numbers whose difference is four.

If eight fours can be achieved, the numbers in the circle must have arcs 1-5-9, 2-6-10, 3-7-11 and 4-8-12.

These must be joined end to end somehow. The loose end '2' must join to '4', and the loose end '3' must join to '1', so now we have two arcs 9-5-1-3-7-11 and 10-6-2-4-8-12.

The only two loose ends that can be joined are 9 & 12, giving 11-7-3-1-5-9-12-8-4-2-6-10, but then we can't join 10 and 11 to form a circle.

So eight can't be achieved.

To show that seven is the maximum, it's enough to find a solution with seven gaps of four. This turns out to be not too hard.